# primefaces 3.2 datatable incell editing not working

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a datatable with incell editing which displays the records correctly but when I try to edit a row, the change is not reflected. Following is the xhtml code:

```
 <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
                <h:outputText value="#{scrip.companyName}"/> 
            </f:facet>
           <f:facet name="input">
               <p:inputText value="#{scrip.companyName}"/> 
            </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Exchange">
            <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
              <h:outputText value="#{scrip.exchange}"/> 
            </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
            <p:selectOneMenu style="width: 150px" value="#{manageScrip.exchange}">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="nse" itemValue="nse"/>
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="bse" itemValue="bse"/>                        
            </p:selectOneMenu>
                    </f:facet>
       </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Brokerage Charge">
            <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
           <h:outputText value="#{scrip.brokerageCharge}"/> 
            </f:facet>
           <f:facet name="input">
           <p:inputText value="#{scrip.brokerageCharge}"/> 
            </f:facet>
       </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Options">
                <p:rowEditor/>

        </p:column>

    </p:dataTable>

    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

Following is the managed bean function:

```
public void updateScrip()
{
    try{
        Integer i=(Integer)dt.getRowKey();
        String str=i.toString();
        sc=(ScripMaster) dt.getRowData(str);

        scripSymbol=sc.getScripSymbol();
        exchange=sc.getExchange();
        companyName=sc.getCompanyName();


        updateScrip(i, scripSymbol, companyName, exchange,);

      }catch(Exception ex){

        }
}
```

Alternatively I also tried:

```
public void updateScrip(RowEditEvent e)
{
    try{
        sc=(ScripMaster) e.getObject();
        scripSymbol=sc.getScripSymbol();
        exchange=sc.getExchange();
        companyName=sc.getCompanyName();
        Integer i=sc.getScripID();
        updateScrip(i, scripSymbol, companyName, exchange);
        }catch(Exception ex){
        }
}
```

---

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" 
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <title>Facelet Title</title>
</h:head>
<h:body> 
    <h:form id="frm">
        <p:commandLink action="/adminpages/addScrip" value="add scrip" ajax="false"/>
        <p:dataTable editable="true" var="scrip" value="#{manageScrip.scripList}" binding="#{manageScrip.dt}" rowKey="#{scrip.scripID}" id="dt">
            <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{manageScrip.updateScrip}" update="@this"/>
            <p:column headerText="Scrip Symbol">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{scrip.scripSymbol}"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:inputText value="#{scrip.scripSymbol}"/>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Company Name">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{scrip.companyName}"/> 
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:inputText value="#{scrip.companyName}"/> 
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Exchange">
                <p:cellEditor>
                   <f:facet name="output">
                      <h:outputText value="#{scrip.exchange}"/> 
                   </f:facet>
                   <f:facet name="input">
                       <p:selectOneMenu style="width: 150px" value="#{manageScrip.exchange}">
                           <f:selectItem itemLabel="nse" itemValue="nse"/>
                          <f:selectItem itemLabel="bse" itemValue="bse"/>                        
                       </p:selectOneMenu>
                   </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Brokerage Charge">
               <p:cellEditor>
                   <f:facet name="output">
                       <h:outputText value="#{scrip.brokerageCharge}"/> 
                   </f:facet>
                   <f:facet name="input">
                       <p:inputText value="#{scrip.brokerageCharge}"/> 
                   </f:facet>
               </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Options">
                <p:rowEditor/>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

Comment: Try to check partial response after edit with firebug.

Comment: i checked the partial response...the input box contains the previous(value before editing) value...

Comment: That's very strange, it should not. Add `<h:messages />` to your .xhtml to check for errors.

Answer (score 1):

The most important part is missing the datatable tag.

Make sure the "editable" attribute is set to true. This attribute was invented in version 3.2 i think, making many onld datatables not editable.

Comment: still the same problem...the changed value in the editable textbox is not set...it takes the previous value...

Answer (score 0):

Try using `h:inputText` instead of `p:inputText`.